# Current in the loop with two protons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, electric-current, charge

Let there be a circular loop of radius r and two protons are moving in this loop with same (and constant speed $v$). They are always  at diametrically opposite ends. They complete one revolution about the centre in time $t$ [which is $2\pi r/v$]

Now the question is, what is the current flowing in the loop?

I have two possible answers: $ i=q/t $ as $q $ charge is flowing through a cross section of loop  and $ i=2q/t$ if $i$ is net charge/time where $q $ is charge on one proton. I think the first one is better but I can't say for sure. Kindly help me out .

Comment: What is $t$, in both cases?

Comment: @probably_someone t is time

Comment: Ok, but which specific interval of time? Think of it this way: most of the time, the amount of charge passing through  given point at a given instant is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case $I=2q/t$. Consider any fixed point on the loop. Over any $t$ the charge passing that point is $2q$

Comment: This is incorrect. Over a small enough $t$, the charge passing that point is $0$. This answer is ***only*** applicable if $t$ is the period of revolution of one proton.

Comment: My statement is correct. In the OP $t$ is defined as $2\pi r/v$, which is indeed the period of revolution. I would have used $T$ for clarity, but didn’t see the point in arguing over notation

Comment: Oh. My mistake. Sorry about that.